# Filter based UnitOfWork not working with async methods on WebAPI (File Uploads)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

A longshot here as I've not found much by way of googling about.

I am using Unit of work and repository patterns with EF on a WebAPI project, and Ninject to manage IoC. To handle multiple file uploads I've got an async method that, althought it does work for processing the files, doesn't save to the DB.

The issue seems to be that the Unit of Work filter for OnActionExecuted fires when the await is called for pulling the files out.

`var files = await _fileHandler.SaveMultipartStream();`

```
public class UnitOfWorkCommitAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private IUnitOfWork _uow;

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        _uow = actionExecutedContext.Request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(IUnitOfWork)) as IUnitOfWork;

        if (actionExecutedContext.Exception == null)
        {
            _uow.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I might improve or adjust my approach to compensate for this effect? Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: Maybe something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502983/async-webapi-actionfilterattribute-an-asynchronous-module-or-handler-completed