# How to identify if the method implementation is marked as async / can be called asynchronously, based only on its interface using Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

**Background Information**

I am building a Roslyn based CodeFix for Visual Studio, that handles the condition where a class does not implement an interface (or is missing part of that interface).

The interfaces will typically be third-party code, e.g. Microsoft's IDocumentClient.

I then create an implementation of that interface, where calls to methods and properties are 'wrapped' by handling their actual execution by a the most relevant candidate from 3 helper methods, as part of a decorated implementation. These helper methods handle scenarios for different return types, including void return, a non-Task type, and a generic Task type.

The helper methods make a call to the `Polly` library; in the case of the helper that returns generic Task types , specifically the `Polly` `ExecuteAsync` method, which performs execution of the passed method delegate, and handles exceptions according to user specified behaviour (retry, circuit breaker, etc).

The code for my project can be found on Github, [Polly.Contrib.Decorator](https://github.com/Pro-Coded/Polly.Contrib.Decorator).

**Problem**

I need to be able to identify if the method that I am creating is asynchronous, by the information contained in the interface declaration.

This would determine two things:

1. If my implementation should be marked with the `async` modifier.
2. If the implementation could be called asynchronously, allowing me to decide if my implementation of the method - which is wrapped - *could* and then, if it *should* be handled asynchronously by my wrapping code.

I cannot rely on any other external information.

**What I have considered**

I have looked at using the return type of the method, to determine if it is a `Task`, but in some cases it is possible that the method declaration in its interface is 'returning void', even though its actual implementation is marked with the async modifier or is callable in an asynchronous way.

Checking the name for the Async suffix is obviously not reliable; not everyone follows such a convention.

**Question**

Is there a reliable method for identifying if a method implementation is asynchronous, i.e. should it be decorated with `async`, and can it be handled asynchronously based only on its interface declaration, using Roslyn?

(Please refer to comment discussion, which indicates the evolution of this question)

Comment: Well, you have to define what you mean by "async" first. For instance, would it be enough that the method returns `Task` or `Task<T>` (or something for which there is a `.GetAwaiter()` instance or extension method available)? What if it is a fire-and-forget event method that is `async void`? The `async` modifier helps rewrite the internals of the method but isn't directly visible on the outside by itself.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - I partially cover that in the 'What I have considered' part - checking for Task or Task<T> was the first option I considered, but I have come across situations where the interface declares a return type of void, but when checking the actual implementation, it is declared with the async modifier. If there is a way to determine from the interface if an implemented method should be created using the async modifier, so that I can cover such edge cases, then that is what I am looking to find. Hope that helps - if so I will add to the question.

Comment: OK, so does your question mean that you want to identify methods rewritten with the `async` keyword?

Comment: Yes - I have just edited the question - hope that is clearer now.

Comment: There is no concept of an `async void` method on an interface.

Comment: @Slaks - ok, so basically, the answer to my question is - check the return type for Task, Task<T>, and just handle any edge cases (if they occur) manually. Which would explain why there is no IsAsync property available when examining an interface?

Comment: @dmcquiggin: Correct-ish.  Note that `await` can be used on any type that has a correct `GetAwaiter()` (but `async` methods must always return a `Task`).  Again, it depends on exactly what you want.

Comment: @SLaks Well, I will only have the interface declaration, so I would not be able to check if there is a GetAwaiter from the information I have to work with. So, looks like return type checking is the only real approach to take. I am still learning Roslyn (obviously!), so wondered if the experts knew of anything I had missed... feel free to correct me if I am wrong, of course...

Comment: @dmcquiggin: No; you can check whether the declared return type declares a `GetAwaiter`.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/01/13/await-anything/  It depends on whether you want to check whether something _is `await`able` or _might be implemented using `async`.

Comment: @SLaks - aha.. excellent... I was certainly not aware of that. Thanks for taking the time to post a reference. Well, that could change my question, while also providing the answer. Thanks for improving my understanding - will update my question.

Comment: @SLaks - and LasseV.Karlsen - you have helped me understand more of what is available to me in terms of information, that also changes the decisions I am able to / should take in my project. I've updated the question with the vital missing part - I defer execution of the implemented method to a helper function - I hope it reflects this more accurately now.

Comment: @SLaks *but `async` methods must always return a `Task`* [Generalized async return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#generalized-async-return-types)

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I believe I might be trying to cover a situation that will not occur, and a simple check of return types is all that is really required, or indeed, possible. I am considering voting to close this Question to avoid wasting peoples time, however the discussion does contain valuable information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

The underlying question is how a library wrapping methods in an interface, should call those methods - with `await` or not.  Not only is whether `async` was declared on the implementations not detectable (from an interface, out of context of the call site), but it is not determining, for this purpose.

- (1) Whether the `async` keyword appears in a method implementation is *not* sufficiently determining for whether a call to it can or should use `await`.
- (2) A method *can* be `await`ed if-and-only-if its return type is `await`able (this is sufficiently determining).
- (3) `async void` methods do not change the above conclusions; an `async void` method does not run any less asynchronously for the fact that you cannot call it with `await`.

**(1) Whether the `async` keyword appears in a method implementation is *not* sufficiently determining for whether a call to it can or should use `await`.**

`async` is not formally part of a method signature.  So `async` is not found in interfaces.  So you can't determine from an interface, if the interface's original author intended method implementations to be written with the `async` keyword or called with `await`.

However, whether the called method is written with the `async` keyword is not actually the determining (/even a sufficiently determining) factor, for whether a method could/should be called with `await`.   There are valid cases for writing methods without the `async` keyword which return `await`ables:

[a] [async-await eilision](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html), as [used extensively by Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/75456beee1c4e25b88ab34057434bdc1eec30480/src/Polly.Shared/PolicyAsync.cs#L27-L252)
[b] an interface mostly used for implementations over I/O, hence declared with `await`able return types, but for which you might also want sometimes to write an in-memory (so synchronous) implementation/interceptor.  [Discussion of common case: sync in-memory cache around async I/O](http://blog.i3arnon.com/2015/11/30/valuetask/)
[c] for test purposes, stubbing out some asynchronous dependency with an in-memory (sync) stub

(It's actually good that `async` isn't part of the method signature, because it permits us occasionally to fulfil with sync implementations, as above.)

**(2) A method can be awaited if-and-only-if its return type is awaitable (this is sufficiently determining); ie the return type is `Task`, `Task<TResult>` or [has a suitable `GetAwaiter()` method](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/01/13/await-anything/)**

The only thing uniquely determining whether a method call *can* be `await`-ed is whether its return type is `await`able.

**(3) `async void` methods do not change the above conclusions**

This addresses `async void` methods at length, because of the comment in the question that the return type of the method might be insufficient, presumably because `void` could not be distinguished (in the interface) from `async void`.

The starting point is that `async void` methods *cannot* be awaited, for the simple reason that, although written with the `async` keyword, they do not return any type that can be `await`-ed.

Does that invalidate our conclusion (2)? (that we can uniquely use whether a method returns an `await`able to determine how to call it).  Are we *losing some capability to run `async void` methods asynchronously*, because we can't `await` them?

Put concretely: say the method behind the interface is `async void Foo()` but all we know about it from the interface is that it is `void Foo()`.  Are we losing some ability for `Foo()` to run asynchronously if we only invoke it `Foo()`?

The answer is no, because of the way `async` methods operate.  `async void` methods behave just as any `async Task/Task<T>` method called with `await`: they run synchronously until their first internal `await`; they then return (`void`, or a `Task` representing their promise to complete), and schedule the remainder of the called method (the part after the first `await`) as a continuation.  That continuation is the part which will run asynchronously, after the `await`ed thing completes.  (That's rather a condensed description, but this is widely blogged; [example discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731376/why-does-an-async-void-method-run-synchronously).)

In other words: The determining factor that some portion of an `async void` method will run asynchronously is not that it is called with `await`, but that, in *its* body, it has an `await` with some meaningful work after it.

**(3b) Another angle on `async void`**

Since the essential q (for the purposes of `Polly.Contrib.Decorator`) is how should we *call* a wrapped method, we can run an alternative thought experiment around `async void` methods.   What if we could (somehow) determine that a `void` method behind an interface had been declared `async void`?  Would we call it any differently?

Back to our example, `async void Foo()`.  What are our choices?  We could `Foo()` directly or `Task.Run(() => Foo())`.

As Stephen Cleary covers, [a library shouldn't use `Task.Run()` on a caller's behalf](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html).  Doing so means the library is taking a choice that work should be offloaded onto a background thread, denying the caller that choice.  (*Note*: per above discussion about how `async void` methods operate, this only applies to the work up to the first `await` within the called method anyway.)

So: even if we could know the method behind `void Foo()` in the interface was `async void Foo()`, `Polly.Contrib.Decorator` should still only call `Foo()` anyway.  If the user wants to immediately offload the work onto a different thread (eg they want to offload it off the GUI thread), they would (before `Polly.Contrib.Decorator` was introduced) be calling that interface method with `Task.Run(() => ...)` anyway.  We don't need to add an extra one.

This conforms with a principle Polly follows and I would recommend other delegate-inflecting libraries should follow: it should have least effect (apart from the declared intended effects) on how users' delegates are run.

---

Key for all the above is that the `async` keyword *doesn't* (in and of itself) *make a method run asynchronously* or even concurrently, so is not the clincher.  The `async` keyword just permits the compiler to chop a method up into a series of chunks at `await` statements; chunks 2..n of such a method run (asynchronously; at a different time) as continuations after the preceding `await`ed call completes.  The caller is (except with `async void` methods) returned a `Task` which is a 'promise' that will complete when the `await`ed method completes.

The fact of being returned that `Task` (or something else implementing `GetAwaiter()`) is the determining factor for whether it can be called with `await`: if the returned type of the method implements this awaitable pattern, it can be awaited.

The existence of async/await elision and the sync-cache-over-async-io pattern in particular, demonstrate that the return type of the called method is key, not whether the implementation used the `async` keyword.

Comment: An excellent in depth explanation, with expert references. For my specific question, this is the solution. Thanks to all who have supplied their expertise, and guided me to fully understand the issue, and available choices, for my scenario.

Comment: +1 to all the other contribs too.  lasse-v-karlsen effectively says the same as my answer, in the first comment.  And SLaks answer with `IsAwaitableNonDynamic()` shows effectively how to determine whether condition (2) in my answer holds.

Answer (score 4):

Roslyn has an internal [`IsAwaitableNonDynamic` extension method](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Shared/Extensions/ISymbolExtensions.cs,916) that does exactly what you're looking for.

You can copy it:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// If the <paramref name="symbol"/> is a method symbol, returns <see langword="true"/> if the method's return type is "awaitable", but not if it's <see langword="dynamic"/>.
    /// If the <paramref name="symbol"/> is a type symbol, returns <see langword="true"/> if that type is "awaitable".
    /// An "awaitable" is any type that exposes a GetAwaiter method which returns a valid "awaiter". This GetAwaiter method may be an instance method or an extension method.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsAwaitableNonDynamic(this ISymbol symbol, SemanticModel semanticModel, int position)
    {
        IMethodSymbol methodSymbol = symbol as IMethodSymbol;
        ITypeSymbol typeSymbol = null;

        if (methodSymbol == null)
        {
            typeSymbol = symbol as ITypeSymbol;
            if (typeSymbol == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (methodSymbol.ReturnType == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // otherwise: needs valid GetAwaiter
        var potentialGetAwaiters = semanticModel.LookupSymbols(position,
                                                               container: typeSymbol ?? methodSymbol.ReturnType.OriginalDefinition,
                                                               name: WellKnownMemberNames.GetAwaiter,
                                                               includeReducedExtensionMethods: true);
        var getAwaiters = potentialGetAwaiters.OfType<IMethodSymbol>().Where(x => !x.Parameters.Any());
        return getAwaiters.Any(VerifyGetAwaiter);
    }

    private static bool VerifyGetAwaiter(IMethodSymbol getAwaiter)
    {
        var returnType = getAwaiter.ReturnType;
        if (returnType == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // bool IsCompleted { get }
        if (!returnType.GetMembers().OfType<IPropertySymbol>().Any(p => p.Name == WellKnownMemberNames.IsCompleted && p.Type.SpecialType == SpecialType.System_Boolean && p.GetMethod != null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var methods = returnType.GetMembers().OfType<IMethodSymbol>();

        // NOTE: (vladres) The current version of C# Spec, §7.7.7.3 'Runtime evaluation of await expressions', requires that
        // NOTE: the interface method INotifyCompletion.OnCompleted or ICriticalNotifyCompletion.UnsafeOnCompleted is invoked
        // NOTE: (rather than any OnCompleted method conforming to a certain pattern).
        // NOTE: Should this code be updated to match the spec?

        // void OnCompleted(Action) 
        // Actions are delegates, so we'll just check for delegates.
        if (!methods.Any(x => x.Name == WellKnownMemberNames.OnCompleted && x.ReturnsVoid && x.Parameters.Length == 1 && x.Parameters.First().Type.TypeKind == TypeKind.Delegate))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // void GetResult() || T GetResult()
        return methods.Any(m => m.Name == WellKnownMemberNames.GetResult && !m.Parameters.Any());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I need a little time to digest this, but my first thought, is as this requires a SemanticModel in order to determine the GetAwaiter, it needs access to the original implementation, rather than the interface, which is all I will have available to me...

Comment: @dmcquiggin: No; it needs the semantic model _for a callsite_ to check whether `GetAwaiter` is visible at a particular callsite.  You could also modify it to just check whether it's `public`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I've taken up enough of your time today, I need to work on this and report back.

Comment: Thank you for this - it has provided me with the mechanism for determining if a suitable GetAwaiter exists, and potentially for me to decide if I call it. I advise readers to also read the comments to the original question, for background.