# How to unregister and register an awaitable Event handler?

Tags: c#, events, async-await

In my code I need to unregister and register an event handler, This works perfect:

```
_favoritsImageView.Click -= _favoritsImageView_Click(this, new CustomeClickEventArgs(item));
_favoritsImageView.Click += _favoritsImageView_Click(this, new CustomeClickEventArgs(item));
void _favoritsImageView_Click(object sender, CustomeClickEventArgs e)
{
       // handles the event
}
```

But for an **awaitable** event handler i have to use this syntax:

```
_favoritsImageView.Click -= async (s, e) => 
{ await _favoritsImageView_ClickAsync(s, new CustomeClickEventArgs(item)); };

_favoritsImageView.Click += async (s, e) => 
{ await _favoritsImageView_ClickAsync(s, new CustomeClickEventArgs(item)); };

async Task _favoritsImageView_ClickAsync(object sender, CustomeClickEventArgs e)
{
       // does async task
}
```

This does not work. Because anonymous methods do not have the same reference. So the first line does not un-register the already registered handler. And eventually the second line adds an extra event handlers to the click.

*Which syntax do I need to use to add and remove an async event handler?*

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: I'm confused, the syntax that you say "works perfect" can't work. Unless `_favoritsImageView_Click` was a method that returns a delegate, which would be really weird.

Comment: @svick I added the `_favoritsImageView_Click` to the sample code. Whats wrong with that??

Comment: What's wrong is that the line `_favoritsImageView.Click += _favoritsImageView_Click(this, new CustomeClickEventArgs(item));` won't compile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Which syntax do I need to use to add and remove an async event
>   handler?

The same syntax as you'd need to use with regular event handlers. You need to save the delegate somewhere so you can later de-register it:

```
private EventHandler eventHandler = 
                            new EventHandler(async (s, e) => await FooAsync(s, e));

public async void SomeOtherEventHandler()
{
    var m = new M();
    m.X += eventHandler;
    m.OnFoo();
    m.X -= eventHandler;
    m.OnFoo();
}

public async Task FooAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Debug.WriteLine("Yay event handler");
}

public class M
{
    public event EventHandler X;
    public void OnX()
    {
        // If you're using C#-6, then X?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);

        var localX = X;
        if (localX != null)
            localX(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

**Edit**:

@svick suggests perhaps another solution, to simply make the method `async void` and register it directly, which is definitely shorter:

```
public async void SomeOtherEventHandler()
{
    var m = new M();
    m.X += FooAsync;
    m.OnFoo();
    m.X -= FooAsync;
    m.OnFoo();
}

public async void FooAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Debug.WriteLine("Yay event handler");
}
```

Comment: You only need to save the delegate if your event handler is a lambda. I think that generally, a better solution is to write the event handler as a  method (`async void` method in this case), which would make the code simpler.

Comment: @svick That's a good idea. Added another version with the direct registration.

Comment: I think it could be great to know what's the difference between a Task return and a void return in this case, and why the @svick answer is good :)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8043882/6400617

Comment: That's a solution I was looking for if you are using async methods inside event handlers and you want to enable/disable/replace them

Answer (score 6):

The synchronous code looks something like this:

```
private void FavoritsImageView_Click(object sender, CustomeClickEventArgs args)
{
    // your synchronous code here
}

…

_favoritsImageView.Click += FavoritsImageView_Click;
_favoritsImageView.Click -= FavoritsImageView_Click;
```

The `async` version looks almost the same, you only need to add `async` to the method:

```
private async void FavoritsImageView_Click(object sender, CustomeClickEventArgs args)
{
    // your asynchronous code here
}

…

_favoritsImageView.Click += FavoritsImageView_Click;
_favoritsImageView.Click -= FavoritsImageView_Click;
```

Note that an event handler is pretty much the only place where you should use `async void`. In most other situations, a synchronous `void` method should be converted to `async Task` method.

Comment: I tried it already. Compiler Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.EventHandler'

Comment: @a.toraby I get that error when I use your syntax `+= FavoritsImageView_Click(this, new CustomeClickEventArgs(item));`. But that's not what I have suggested.

Comment: @downvoter Care to explain what you think is wrong with my answer?