# Wait till task returns

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

How do i wait my method for a task to complete before the method returns.

```
public async void  barcodescanner()
{
    var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
    barcode =  await scanner.Scan();
}
```

Definition of `scaner.Scan()`:

```
public Task<Result> Scan();
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but the code snippet insertion was not working properly. It looks it has changed. And I don't think i need a negative reputation for no fault of mine

Comment: What platform are you running this on?

Comment: @Enigmativity : Xamarin.Android

Comment: Then you probably really shouldn't try to block this method. That's how mobile apps crash - the OS doesn't like apps that hang.

Comment: True. But that call is suppose to load a barcode scanner, the result need to be obtained before i continoue

Comment: But that's what `async`/`await` does for you. It makes the code appear to wait for the result, but the UI remains responsive. You then need to change the `void` to `Task` to be able to await this code when you call it. Just as Alexei says in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't wait for result of `async void` method - it is explicitly "fire and forget" behavior.

If you want to wait for completion - return `Task` and `.Wait` on it

```
public async Task  barcodescanner() {...}

barcodescanner().Wait();
```

Notes:

- synchronously waiting for async methods can cause deadlocks and in general not recommended - so do it on your own risk. See [await vs Task.Wait - Deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock) for details
- Difference between `void` and `Task` return covered in [What's the difference between returning void and returning a Task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043296/whats-the-difference-between-returning-void-and-returning-a-task) answer.

Comment: Calling `Wait()` will deadlock the UI.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Not sure what your comment is about. If you are asking question - link to explanation is in the answer...

Answer (score 0):

You could always do this:

```
public void barcodescanner()
{
    var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
    barcode =  scanner.Scan().Result;
}
```

Comment: Won't that block the UI?

Comment: @PauloMorgado - Yes, that's what the OP asked for. It's not what you should do, of course.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "deadlock".

Comment: @PauloMorgado - Why should it deadlock?