# Race condition with async/await, how to resolve

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, mvvm, async-await

I have a problem with async/await in C#, i need it to get some object called Trades, after i get it, it needs to SAVE it. Problem is, with async/await, it is doing the SAVE first, and then go and get my trade objects. How do i ensure i get the objects first, and then does the saving.... here is my code...

```
    private async void OnRefresh()
    {
        try
        {
            var trades = await ExchangeServiceInstance.GetTrades("");
            mmTrades = new ObservableCollection<EEtrade>(trades);
            tradeListView.ItemsSource = mmTrades;
        }
        catch { }
    }

    public async void OnSignalReceived()
    {
        // THIS NEEDS TO FINISH FIRST, BUT IT DOESN'T
        await tradeListView.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync((Action)async delegate
        {
            if (ExchangeServiceInstance.SelectedTabIndex == CURRENT_TAB_INDEX_ITEM)
            {
                await Task.Delay(MMConfig.DELAYMILLISEC);
                OnRefresh();
            }
        });

        // SOMEHOW THIS GETS CALLED FIRST BEFORE THE ABOVE GETS TO FINISH!
        await OnSaveTrades();
    }

    public async Task<int> OnSaveTrades()
    {
        foreach (var trade in mmTrades)
        {
            await ExchangeServiceInstance.OnInsertDoneTrade(trade);
        }
        return mmTrades.Count;
    }
```

Any ideas guys? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `OnRefresh` method. Because the return type is `void` the method is not awaited [[Check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8043882/3888657)]. In addition you dont even try to await for the method inside your delegate

Changing the method to the following:

```
private async Task OnRefresh()
    {
        try
        {
            var trades = await ExchangeServiceInstance.GetTrades("");
            mmTrades = new ObservableCollection<EEtrade>(trades);
            tradeListView.ItemsSource = mmTrades;
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

And await this method inside your delegate, should solve your problem:

```
public async void OnSignalReceived()
    {
        // THIS NEEDS TO FINISH FIRST, BUT IT DOESN'T
        await tradeListView.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync((Action)async delegate
        {
            if (ExchangeServiceInstance.SelectedTabIndex == CURRENT_TAB_INDEX_ITEM)
            {
                await Task.Delay(MMConfig.DELAYMILLISEC);
                await OnRefresh();
            }
        });

        // SOMEHOW THIS GETS CALLED FIRST BEFORE THE ABOVE GETS TO FINISH!
        await OnSaveTrades();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of `(Action)async` is basically the same as `async void`, and `async void` is *almost always* a mistake. Specifically, the consumer **cannot** know the outcome (unless it faults synchronously). The dispatcher here *isn't really thinking of `async`*.

If we assume that you **must** use the dispatcher here, perhaps a *workaround* might be to use something like a `SemaphoreSlim` (or maybe a `TaskCompletionSource<something>`) that you signal *at the end* of your async work (even in the exception case), and then await *that*; untested, but:

```cs
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
await tradeListView.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync((Action)async delegate
{
    try {
        if (ExchangeServiceInstance.SelectedTabIndex == CURRENT_TAB_INDEX_ITEM)
        {
            await Task.Delay(MMConfig.DELAYMILLISEC);
            OnRefresh();
        }
        tcs.TrySetResult(true);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        tcs.TrySetException(ex);
    }
});
await tcs.Task; // ensure the async work is complete

await OnSaveTrades();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using the async void pattern a lot. This is really bad practice for a [number of reasons](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170721-00/?p=96665). You should stop doing that.

The problem here is that `OnRefresh` is again an async void method that can't be awaited but should be:

```
private async Task OnRefresh()
{
    try
    {
        var trades = await ExchangeServiceInstance.GetTrades("");
        mmTrades = new ObservableCollection<EEtrade>(trades);
        tradeListView.ItemsSource = mmTrades;
    }
    catch { }
}
```

In your `OnSignalReceived` method change the call to `OnRefresh();` to `await OnRefresh();`